# Weird issue trying to print ApplicationContext content in a JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model

I am going crazy here. Just trying to print all the Spring beans in a JSP. I am using `getBeanDefinitionNames`, `getPackage`(), `getName`() from applicationContext to print some bean names and their packages. 
Everything runs fine and I could verify all the beans with a debugger, but as soon as I populate the list on JSP with a populated model object(list of objects containing bean attributes), every element of the list shows:

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver
```

and it's corresponding package:  `package org.springframework.web.servlet.view`

Why is it acting this way?

Comment: Hi, I added the code snippet.

Comment: Please also post the JSP so we can see how you display the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've instantiated a single `SpringBeanStore` object and re-used that same object in your for loop, adding it X number of times in your result set. It will obviously hold the value of the last bean in your `myBeans`.

Initialize the `SpringBeanStore` inside your enhanced for loop.